# Inflate gzipped bytes on an iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, gzip

I'm trying to inflate a gzipped byte buffer on an iOS 5.0.
I am using the NSData category found at [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory).
However, every time I call gzipInflate on an NSData object, it returns "nil".

I have tried linking to libz, building for both the simulator, and a device, and tried a clean build, but none have succeeded.

The NSData object contains valid gzipped data.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT1: Here's the code I'm using.

```
            uint8_t appendArray[1];
            for (int i=0; i != 1024; i++) {
                appendArray[0] = [self readByte]; // neccessary, because [self readByte] returns a uint8_t.
                [tempdata appendBytes:appendArray length:1];
            }
            NSData *almostdata = [tempdata gzipInflate]; // Returns nil 
            assert(almostdata != nil); // Fails
```

Tempdata is an NSMutableData object, with 1024 bytes of capacity. readByte is a method to read one byte from a network stream.
The gzipInflate method comes from [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory).
The data from the stream is 1024 bytes long, while compressed.

EDIT2: It's a Z_BUF_ERROR, and yet the output buffer is more than large enough for the bytes.

EDIT3: This problem was only caused because I misread the network protocol. I just had to combine ALL of the data from the stream before trying to ungzip.

Comment: I've added the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This problem was only caused because I misread the network protocol. I just had to combine ALL of the data from the stream before trying to ungzip.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see all your code - so this is a bit of a stab in the dark - but it looks like you're reading into `uselessArray` - but you're appending data from `appendedArray`...

Should this:

```
uselessArray[0] = [self readByte]; // neccessary, because [self readByte] returns a uint8_t.
[tempdata appendBytes:appendArray length:1];
```

be this:

```
uselessArray[0] = [self readByte]; // neccessary, because [self readByte] returns a uint8_t.
[tempdata appendBytes:uselessArray length:1];
```

?

Comment: It would have been great if that was the fix, but it was just a problem from copying and pasting to here.